# How to add fade in/fade out effect on window created using Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a palette window which is the topmost window and I want to add fade in/ fade out effect when window appears and disappears respectively.
The window currently auto hides upon losing focus and appears otherwise.
To hide and display window I am using

```
showWindow(handle, SW_HIDE)
```

Is there any way to add desired effects to the window?

**Bonus Question :** I want the edges of the windows to be rounded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AnimateWindow` for the fading.
`SetWindowRgn` for rounded corners.